# change primary key of sentry 2 user migration table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I have tried this code and run the migrations that ships with sentry 2 by doing this:
`php artisan migrate:--package cartalyst/sentry.`

I was able to create the user, group, and other tables in my database.

How do i change the `ID` column of the user table from being the `PRIMARY KEY` to `userID` which i added as a migration?

Comment: generate a fresh migration that adds userID to the users table , then set primary on the column, that should fix your issue.

Comment: But it already has 'id' as a primary key, so it tells me that i cant have two primary keys, and whats the effect setting another primary key will have on the referential integrity?

Comment: are you want a rename column 'id' to 'userID' on sentry users table ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Generate new fresh migration using `php artisan migrate:make` and write below code

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropPrimary('users_id_primary');
        $table->integer("userID");
        $table->primary('userID');
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropPrimary('userID');
        $table->dropColumn('userID');
        $table->primary('users_id_primary');

    });
}
```

Then after run `php artisan migrate`

**Next** and change you `User` Model

```
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User as SentryUserModel;

class User extends SentryUserModel {

    protected $primaryKey = 'userID';
}
```

**Next**

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

Next open the config file in `app/config/packages/cartalyst/sentry` and edit

```
'users' => array(
 'model' => 'User',
 ...
 ),
```

Hope it will be helpful :)

Comment: Will this affect anything in the referencing? cos i think somehow, sentry must have tied the primary key which is 'id' with something somewhere or so. I just want to be sure that after changing the primary key to another column, it wont cause any problems..

Comment: will this change affect places in sentry code where 'id' has been used to query the database?